# Function in VBA returns #Value in one Sheet but works in another

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function in VBA that makes a few operations by calling other smaller functions. This function doesn't work in any sheets, just in one. In the sheets it doesn't work it just gets out of the whole algorithm when getting the value from another function.

This is my `Function determinarCantidadPorPedido(ByVal material As String, ByVal mes As String)`

```
 Dim demanda As Double
    Dim pProgramado As Double
    Dim numPedidos As Integer

    demanda = determinarDemanda(material, mes)

    Call contarProductosMateriales

    Sheets("LlegadaMateriales").Activate
    Dim fila As Integer
    Dim columna As Integer

    For i = 1 To numMateriales Step 1
        If Sheets("LlegadaMateriales").Cells(1 + i, 1) = material Then
            fila = 1 + i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    For j = 1 To 12 Step 1
        If Sheets("LlegadaMateriales").Cells(1, j + 1) = mes Then
            columna = j + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    pProgramado = Sheets("LlegadaMateriales").Cells(fila, columna)

    numPedidos = darCantidadPedidos(determinarDiasMes(mes), darLeadTime(material))

    determinarCantidadPorPedido = WorksheetFunction.Round((demanda - pProgramado) / numPedidos, 0)
```

and it calls `Public Function determinarDemanda(ByVal material As String, ByVal mes As String) As Double`

```
    Dim filaProducto As Double
    Dim numMat As Double
    Dim columnaDemanda As Double

    Worksheets("ProductosYMateriales").Activate
   numMat = Sheets("ProductosYMateriales").Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    For i = 1 To numMat Step 1
        If Sheets("ProductosYMateriales").Cells(i + 2, 1) = material Then
            filaProducto = i + 2
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    For j = 1 To 12 Step 1
        If Sheets("Demanda").Cells(1, j + 2) = mes Then
            columnaDemanda = j + 2
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Dim numProd As Double
    numProd = Sheets("ProductosYMateriales").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 2).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
    Dim demanda As Double
    demanda = 0

    For k = 1 To numProd Step 1
        Dim x As Double
        x = Sheets("Demanda").Cells(k + 1, columnaDemanda)
        Dim y As Double
        y = Sheets("ProductosYMateriales").Cells(filaProducto, k + 1)
        Dim prod As Double
        prod = x * y

        demanda = demanda + prod
    Next

    determinarDemanda = demanda
```

and `Function determinarCantidadPorPedido(ByVal material As String, ByVal mes As String)`

```
Dim demanda As Double
Dim pProgramado As Double
Dim numPedidos As Integer

demanda = determinarDemanda(material, mes)

Call contarProductosMateriales

Sheets("LlegadaMateriales").Activate
Dim fila As Integer
Dim columna As Integer

For i = 1 To numMateriales Step 1
    If Sheets("LlegadaMateriales").Cells(1 + i, 1) = material Then
        fila = 1 + i
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For j = 1 To 12 Step 1
    If Sheets("LlegadaMateriales").Cells(1, j + 1) = mes Then
        columna = j + 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

pProgramado = Sheets("LlegadaMateriales").Cells(fila, columna)

numPedidos = darCantidadPedidos(determinarDiasMes(mes), darLeadTime(material))

determinarCantidadPorPedido = WorksheetFunction.Round((demanda - pProgramado) / numPedidos, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One Problem is in this Line:

```
numMat = Sheets("ProductosYMateriales").Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

when you call `Cells`, this reference the current active sheet. Therefore you will get different results, if you call the function on different sheets.

You will have to specify from what sheets you want to reference the cells. I guess you want this:

```
numMat = Sheets("ProductosYMateriales").Range(Sheets("ProductosYMateriales").Cells(3, 1), Sheets("ProductosYMateriales").Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```